# How can you bind to a ViewModel property from a DataTemplate

Tags: c#, xaml, winui-3

So I have a DataTemplate that I'm trying to bind to. The idea is that there is a checkbox in the app that can be used to turn what are considered "Advanced Values" on or off. I figured I could use an IValueConverter and pass in whether or not the value is advanced and whether or not the CheckBox is checked. The problem is that I can't figure out how to bind anything outside of the DataTemplate's x:DataType. Below is an approximation of the code:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="ShowAdvancedCheckBox" IsChecked="{x:Bind ViewModel.ShowAdvanced}"/>
...
<DataTemplate x:Key="StringParameterTemplate" x:DataType="datatypes:BatchParameter">
    <TextBox
        Header="{x:Bind Name}"
        Text="{x:Bind Value, Mode=TwoWay}"
        Visibility="{x:Bind IsAdvanced, Converter={StaticResource IsAdvancedToVisibility}, ConverterParameter=???}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

I'm unsure what to put into the ConverterParameter though. Any advice?

Comment: The `ConverterParameter` is not a dependency property and cannot be bound to anything at all.

Comment: In that case, if I bound Visibility to a function, how do I do a proper INofityPropertyChanged call to it since it's not a property?

Answer (score 1):

When you are in DataTemplate, Your DataContext is not your ViewModel.
To bind the ViewModel property, Set x:Name for your page or UserControl (XAML) and Bind using ElementName eg:

```
<UserControl
...
x:Name = ShowAdvancedView>
...
<DataTemplate x:Key="StringParameterTemplate" x:DataType="datatypes:BatchParameter">
<TextBox
    Header="{x:Bind Name}"
    Text="{x:Bind Value, Mode=TwoWay}"
    Visibility="{Binding ViewModel.ShowAdvanced,ElementName = ShowAdvancedView, Mode = OneWay, Converter={StaticResource IsAdvancedToVisibility}}" />
</DataTemplate>
</UserControl>
```

When using this code UserControl is the source of Binding and Its DataContext is your ViewModel.